# How to vertically center equation number in single long continued fraction?

Tags: numbering, amsmath, fractions

Suppose I would like to get an equation number on the left into the middle of some long continued fraction like this

[image]

Is there any simple way to do it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
z(s)= z_1 +
\cfrac{1}{y_2+
 \cfrac{1}{z_3+ 
  \cfrac{1}{y_4+  
   \cfrac{1}{\ddots \raisebox{-2ex}{$+\cfrac{1}{z_{2n-3} + \cfrac{1}{y_{2n-2} + \cfrac{1}{z_{2n - 1} + \cfrac{1}{y_{2n}}}}}$}}}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To me it makes more sense if the equation number is vertically aligned with the = symbol and the main fraction line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embed the formula in `gathered`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
z(s)= z_1 +
\cfrac{1}{y_2+
 \cfrac{1}{z_3+
  \cfrac{1}{y_4+
   \cfrac{1}{\ddots
    \raisebox{-2ex}{$+\cfrac{1}{z_{2n-3} +
     \cfrac{1}{y_{2n-2} +
      \cfrac{1}{z_{2n - 1} +
       \cfrac{1}{y_{2n}}}}}$}}}}}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]